# How to add clickable areas to uploaded images in Nodejs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, image-processing, npm, collectionfs

I want to add the ability for a user to tag photos at specific locations of choice when uploading them. Please which `npm` package(s) can I use to do that. I am currently working on a `Meteor/react` app, and using `CollectionFS` for saving images

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use svg images. These images can be opened in a text editor and you can assign id's to different sections. I had a task once to make different parts(muscles) of a a body clickable. I used [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/main.html) to map different muscles and assigned id's to those muscles. Then just used javascript to add click events to individual muscles.

Comment: any `npm` modules I can use to accomplish this with?

Comment: Not that I am aware of but if you are uploading an svg image then it means you will retrieve it and use it on the client. SVG images are of this format. 
 `<path id="sauce" fill="#f00" … />` and you can do `$('#sauce').on('click',function(){ … });` to make that path clickable. A path represents a particular part of an image.